# Editing metadata of a video file in Android

Tags: android, video, metadata, avi

I'm want to be able to programmatically edit the metadata of a video file after it has already been saved. Can someone point me in the right direction?  Are the MediaSession and MediaMetadata classes the ones to use?

Comment: Have you found solution ?

Comment: @oshurmamadov I don't think I ever found a solution.